# auto width for jquery accordion menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, width, accordion

Here is a source which I found for horizontal accordion menu but the problem is I need the content part width to be auto. Try to remove the text from the content part and add only one word and see the effect tat, it still takes the some amount of width.

http://www.ajaxshake.com/demo/EN/526/420eaebd/horizontal-accordion-with-autoplay-easy-accordion.html

How do I get the auto width?

Comment: auto width will just lead to messy animations. Use fixed widths

Comment: But the content is generating dynamically so I cant fix the width. Actually the content is in the form of boxes with ul list so boxes are not fixed